# Loop the onchange select option

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to put the `onchange` function of `select` option in the loop. Particularly a `for` loop for me to change the `id` of the select tag with an incremental variable. The `select` tag in HTML is also in the loop with the id that is changing through an incremented PHP variable

```js
$(function() {
  var row = document.getElementById("comments").textContent;
  var text = 1;
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
    $('#part').html(text).change(function() {
      var display = $('#part').html(text).find(":selected").val();
      $('#resone').val(display);
    })
    text++;
  }
})
```

```html
  Item Name Price Qty Total
  <td>Discount</td>
</tr>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_item WHERE order_id = {$edit['order_id']}";
  $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  $count = 1; 
  $counts = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
  
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
  { ?>
    <div id="comments" hidden>
      <?php echo $counts; ?>
    </div>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="resone"></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo ucfirst(getProductNameFromId($con, $row['product_id']));?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['rate']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['total']; ?>
      </td>

      <td id="as">
        <select name="artist_1" id="part<?php echo $count; ?>">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
          <option value="1">lawa</option>
          <option value="2">laaswa</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $count++;
  } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you are duplication id's and that is bad. You can't have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: that is my issue, when i populate two select tag with same id , the other one select tag is not working , that is why i put it on loop to manipulate the id value

Comment: Just give the selects a common class and that will solve lots of problems

Comment: and it is still not working now i put both onchange function and select tag on loop. I just want to manipulate the value of id for both jquery and select tag

Comment: A better approach is to remove all the `id` attributes and use common classes instead. Also note that the HTML you're creating is invalid - a `div` cannot be a child of a `table`

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Comment: Remove the id "part" and give it the class instead class="part" then use `$('.part')`

Comment: i have tested in two columns the first column with select tag is working but it change also the second column input type. the second column with select tag is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@llea 123

I'm not using jQuery but you could do:

```js
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName('square')

for (const square of squares) {
   square.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // do what you want with e.currentTarget
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
 $gategory = $_GET["gategory"];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_item WHERE order_id = {$edit['order_id']}";
  $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  $count = 1; 
  $counts = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
  
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
  { ?>
    <div id="comments" hidden>
      <?php echo $counts; ?>
    </div>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="resone"></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo ucfirst(getProductNameFromId($con, $row['product_id']));?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['rate']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['total']; ?>
      </td>

      <td id="as">
        <select name="artist_1" id="part<?php echo $count; ?>">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
          <option value="1">lawa</option>
          <option value="2">laaswa</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $count++;
  } ?>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".category").on('change', function(){
      var value = $('select[name=artist_1] option').filter(':selected').val()
      window.location.href="index.php?gategory="+value;
});

</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you. how about the loop inside the jquery? I like to put the onchange function inside a loop to manipulate the target id of a function

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you did a loop with html inside: the id must be unique. That's why javascript doesn't works

You could use getElementsByClassName and then you can iterate on each to put an event listener

Comment: thank you. how about the loop inside the jquery? I like to put the onchange function inside a loop to manipulate the target id of a function

Comment: @llea 123 you could see formatted response below